# Expand a column to fill empty content without fixed width?

Tags: css

I have a scenario that I've been trying to figure out through any means possible, whether html tables/floats/display:table. I have a 3 column row and I'd like the outer columns to wrap the content inside, and the middle column to expand to fill all empty space.

However Im looking for a solution without a fixed width, as this object will be nested multiple times in which case the overall width will shrink. Of the three columns, I will always know the width of the rightmost column, if that matters.

Here is a fiddle for what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/gHUxy/2/

I know flexbox looks like it was made for this stuff but its just not widespread enough yet for me to use it. Is it even possible?

edit - i dont need to support ie6/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using jQuery. Please include the latest jQuery Lib.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    section {
      display:table;
      width: 100%;
      border:1px solid red;
    }

    div {
      display: table-cell;         
    }

    .leader {
      background: grey;
    }

    .right{
      float: right;   
    }
    .left {
      float:left;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".leader").width($("section").width() - ($(".left").width() +$(".right").width()));
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="left">
         Variable wrappable content
    </div>            
    <div class="leader">
        <!--empty space-->
    </div>            
    <div class="right">
        <!--fixed length-->
       Date
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt seem to be working (im using chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/gHUxy/6/

Comment: Hi, have you included the latest jQuery library? You can download it from http://jquery.com/download/.

Comment: Yes did you click on the jsfiddle link?

Comment: I dont understand what the javascript is doing. If you remove it it behaves exactly the same

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned up the javascript and this ended up working out pretty well. Here is the latest fiddle if you are curious: http://jsfiddle.net/KSmvr/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `width` of the columns that are **not** your "middle" column to `1px`. This would force them to only expand until they fit their content. Here's a sample, HTML:

```
<table class = "main">
    <tr><td class = "notmid">Glee Glee Glee Glee Glee Glee</td><td>is</td><td class = "notmid">awesome!</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
}
.main {
    width: 100%;
}
.main .notmid {
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/KJKeF/1/).

Hope that helped in any manner!

Comment: Hmm interesting, I tried this but unfortunately if the first column is more than one word it wraps after each word. But thanks for the idea, maybe theres some way to expand on it. Problem is the content may actually need to wrap if its long enough

Comment: @user842800 See edit. Basically, just add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.notmid`. The demo is updated, too.

Comment: Well like I thought that would only help situations where the text never wraps, but sometimes it will need to naturally wrap if it gets too long.